# How to access all array values from JSON in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json

If I have a database schema set up like this

```
{ "name":  "Microsoft",
     "field": [
         "technology",
         "ai",
         "etc"
     ]
}
```

how can I get the data from angular? Calling:

```
{{company.field[]}}
```

doesn't work. I can only call an array index like

```
{{company.field[1]}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The property `field` is not nested under the `name` property.

To access the array values you'll need to do `company.field[n]` where `n` is the index of the item or just dump the entire array like `company.field`.

See my [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/SamuelToh/fb3w5s1L/7/).

Comment: My mistake. Messed up writing on my phone. In your example it prints out company.field[1]. How can I get everything inside company.field[].

Comment: @TerraNuva try `{{company.field}}` without `[]`. I have updated my JSFiddle.

Answer (score 2):

Since the field property is an array, are you looking to iterate through to get those values?

You can use the ng-repeat directive

```
<div ng-repeat="item in company.field">
{{item}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 //try this
 <div ng-repeat="val in company">
    {{val.name}}
    <div ng-repeat="obj in val.field">
       {{obj.technology}}
       {{obj.ai}}
       {{obj.etc}}
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>

  var company =  { "name":  "Microsoft",
     "field": [
         "technology",
         "ai",
         "etc"
     ]
}
for(i=0;i<company.field.length;i++){
console.log(company.field[i])

}

</script>
```